# show the text same as saved in database

Tags: php, kohana

```
str = "I am  So        Coool       Because I    can do stuff            Like THIS!";
```

I used the php function nl2br() to show the text as like the same in text area.

```
echo nl2br(str)
```

It is replacing  the space between the `So and Coool,I and can,stuff and Like` from the above example.

Output i am getting is `I am  So Coool Because I can do stuff Like THIS!`

Expecting is `I am  So        Coool       Because I    can do stuff            Like THIS!`

How to show the paragraph text along with spaces.

Comment: Have u tried `<pre>` ? `echo '<pre>'. $str .'</pre>';`

Comment: javascript trim ??? You can try trim in php like: `echo '<pre>'. trim($str) .'</pre>';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are compacted in HTML because there's a distinction between how HTML is formatted and how it should be rendered. 
You can use pre tag to show your text as is.
for example try to use

```
echo '<pre>'.$str.'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by browser wrapping.

To show multiple spaces within HTML you have few options:

A - Wrap your code in `<pre>` element

```
<pre><?php echo $text; ?></pre>
```

B - Add `white-space: pre` to parent element ([W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp))

```
.text-wrapper {
   white-space: pre;
}
```

C - Replace spaces with `&nbsp;`, (this in non-breaking whitespace - your text will not wrap from spaces)

```
<?php echo str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $text); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the browser is the issue here since all the spaces are in the html code.

Try it with `<pre></pre>` tags